# FacebookSDK search by username/pagename

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to access public information for a user based on their username/pagename.

I'm doing this:

```
$uname = 'csga5000';

$session = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => self::$FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => self::$FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2'
]);

try {
    // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
    $response = $session->get('/search?q='+$uname+'&type=user');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    print_r($e);
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

But the exception is thrown, here is the output:

```
Graph returned an error: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: v2.20
```

Alternatively(Got this from looking at the source code)

```
$response = $session->sendRequest('GET','/search',['q'=>$uname,'type'=>'user']);
```

Returns "Graph returned an error: An access token is required to request this resource."  I stole a reference from somewhere using app id and secret as the token in this format:

```
$response = $session->sendRequest('GET','/search',['q'=>$uname,'type'=>'user'], self::$FACEBOOK_APP_ID.'|'.self::$FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET);
```

This throws: "Graph returned an error: A user access token is required to request this resource."

I don't understand why a USER access token is required :/

Anyone know how to search for a user based on username in php?  I've seen other examples that were slightly outdated, but I was pretty much the same as what they claim worked.

**Edit:**
The information we want to acquire is primarily follower count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the case that it's not possible(at the time) to access more than a user's name publicly.  OAuth is required to access the public profile (which is a default permission).

Using the graph api explorer you can verify this using the endpoint /{user-id} and trying to get additional information for a user with whatever id.

The return is like this:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "id": "100003216243221"
}
```

You can get first and last name as well, by appending:

```
?fields=name,first_name,last_name
```

But access to other information fails, even when public. (I only tested location, which clearly has an additional permission).

**EDIT!**

**HOWEVER:**
If you wish to access a **facebook page**, some information is accessible.

This is some of the information returned if no fields are specified: about, id, can_post, category, check_ins, has_added_app, is_community_page, is_published, likes, link, location, name, phone, talking_about_count, username, website, were_here_count.

Using the endpoint:

```
{page-username-or-id}?fields=engagement,is_permanently_closed,emails,picture
```

Can retrieve other information fields (assuming they're public).

So code for this:
**Facebook sdk v4**:

```
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
$session->validate();

$ret = new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'GET', '/'.$uname.'?fields=name,engagement,phone,link,is_community_page,is_permanently_closed,influences,hometown,general_info,emails,bio,birthday,description,location,username,likes,picture'
    );

$ret = $ret->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

If you want to catch exceptions, you can look the thrown exceptions up: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/

This works for the same request for **facebook sdk v5** (though, I don't know that the way I called send request is advised):

```
$uname = 'tbdsolutions5000';

$session = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => self::$FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => self::$FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2'
]);
try {

    $response = $session->sendRequest('GET','/'.$uname,[
            //Optionally:
            //'fields' => 'comma, separated, fields'
        ],
        self::$FACEBOOK_APP_ID.'|'.self::$FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
    );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    print_r($e);
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$response = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can´t search for users by username anymore. Earlier this was possible by just using a simple API call: `graph.facebook.com/username`

This does not work anymore, and the Search API only allows to search for the name (first/last). You are not supposed to use the username anymore.

That being said, you need to authorize yourself and use a User Token, as the error message tells you. That´s just how it is, and you can read it in the docs too:

> - Searches across Page and Place objects requires an app access token.
> - All other endpoints require a user access token.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Can my application access a public user information in some way?  I have the username, all I need is the id, I believe.  In the event that those look-ups require a user token, is permission limited to that user, or could I use my own dev user to get arround this permission barrier?

Comment: you can only get information about a user if that user authorized your app. again, you are not supposed to use the username anymore. people who did not authorize your app are none of your business, for privacy reasons you can´t access them in any way.

Comment: you can only use your dev user for yourself. don´t try to circumvent the system ;)

Comment: The public information system is a convenience we offer clients.  On various social media platforms we pull user information publicly, so they don't have to oauth connect their accounts.  The information I wish to access is public, I could go find it right now via my web browser, I just want my API to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  You're right, all user information except name, requires oath.  Pages don't though, which is still useful for me.

Comment: yes, please accept my answer :) - pages are another story, of course. pages are always available with the api - except when they are restricated by age or location. but it´s about user profiles in this thread anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your time, and I did up vote you.  I accepted my own answer, as I spent a lot of time explaining what you can do.  I adapted the page name to list more what I had originally intended, which included pages and normal users.  I wish I could accept "both".. I'll encourge people to upvote your answer as well.